# Sort Array javascript according to sizes

Tags: javascript

I have an array which i am trying to sort according to real world sizes

```
["s", "m", "l", "xl", "xxl", "xs"].sort(function(a,b){ 
    if(a === "xs") 
});
```

I am getting this array as  response and I have to modify it in front end
I have tried to sort it out but i cant find suitable condition to do
What should I do such that array is sorted in this order

```
["xs","s", "m", "l", "xl", "xxl"]
```

Even If any size is missing it should be in correct order for instance If medium size is not available it should be in correct order

```
["xs","s", "l", "xl", "xxl"]
```

Comment: I can't change backend its not allowed I have to do it on front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object here as a dictionary.

> Fetching data from object is much better than array

```js
const sizes = {
  xs: 100,
  s: 200,
  m: 300,
  l: 400,
  xl: 500,
  xxl: 600,
};

const arr = ["s", "m", "l", "xl", "xxl", "xs"];
const result = arr.sort((a, b) => sizes[a] - sizes[b]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what an overhead. you have already a data structure which has an access of O(n) and use another structure with the same.

Comment: Map looks cool but not needed. Just use `sizes[a]` instead of `dict.get(a)`.

Comment: Yeah, there is no need of Map, Code edited, thanks for the feedback 

Answer (score 2):

Use the index position of an ordered array:

```js
const order = ["xs", "s", "m", "l", "xl", "xxl"];

const orderedArray = ["s", "m", "l", "xl", "xxl", "xs"].sort((a, b) => {
  return order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b)
})

console.log(orderedArray) // ["xs", "s", "m", "l", "xl", "xxl"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating an array of objects, with the corresponding sizes:

```
var sizes = [
  { size: 'xs', value: 0},
  { size: 's', value: 1},
  { size: 'm', value: 2},
  { size: 'l', value: 3},
  { size: 'xl', value: 4},
  { size: 'xxl', value: 5}
];
```

Then sort based on the values:

```
// sort by value
sizes.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
});
```